# How should I convert an increasing number array into a character array so that I can use the atoi function

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include<sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

string IntToString(int&);
int main()
{
    char output[45] = "0";
    int str = 0;
    char enc[8] = "0";
    int enc1[1] = { 0 };
    int arrayLength = sizeof(enc1) / sizeof(enc1[0]);
    string strs;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
    {
        int enc1[1];
        enc1[0]={ i };
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
            int& temp = enc1[i];
            
            strs+= IntToString(temp);
            enc == strs.c_str();
        }
        
        if (atoi(enc)+46*2 == 3251)
        {
            output == enc;
            
        }
            
    }
    printf("%s", output);
}

string IntToString(int& i)
{
    string s;
    stringstream ss(s);
    ss << i;
    return ss.str();
}
```

This is what I want to convert an integer array into a string by continuously increasing, and then convert the string into a number according to the atoi function as a function，I've looked at tutorials on using stoi and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate it if you could help me[image]

Comment: Fyi, `std::to_string` makes at least half of this go away, but I'll be honest; I have absolutely no idea what on earth this code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: `output == enc` has no effect, should it be `output = enc`? Same with `enc == strs.c_str()`. As these are char arrays the assignment won't compile, you'd be better off using `std::string`, otherwise you'll need to use `srtcmp` to compare the arrays

Comment: `enc1` only has a single element so `enc1[i]` had undefined behaviour

Comment: I want to convert an integer array into a string array, but I don't know how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You code has a lot of problems...

As for your question, if you want to convert an integer into a string, just use `std::string your_string = std::to_string(you_integer);`.

Then some of the problems that you have:

`enc == strs.c_str();` <- the operator `==` is not the assignment operator. What you do here is that you compare two pointers, that is probably not what you intended, because you don't even check the result of the comparison.

Don't use the loop index `i` in a nested loop when it is already in use.

Don't use char arrays in C++ unless you have an explicit reason to use it. Even if you are worried about performance, for small strings you can look at `std::string` as a `char` array. And you cannot have large strings, because the largest possible integer value represented as a string still counts as a small string.

If you have arrays with constant size, use `#define ARRAY_SIZE 15` or something like this rather than what you did.

Don't pass primitive types by reference if you don't have to. As far as I know, only `double` and `long long` are larger (on most platforms) than a reference, so you won't gain anything from passing by reference. On the contrary, the optimizer won't like you if you use unnecessary aliasing.

I have to say, I am not sure that I understood your goal correctly. But as I understood it, you want to convert an integer array into a string then to an integer. I am not quiet sure why you would want to do that, but that's on me.

The following code does what I think you wanted. It converts an integer array into an integer by first converting it into a string. But even so, you cannot increase the array size much, because `std::stoi` will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception when the number in the string would be too large for an integer.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 9

int int_arr_to_int (const int * const arr) {
    std::string str;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        str += std::to_string(i);
    }
    return std::stoi(str);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int arr[15] = { 0 };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    std::cout << int_arr_to_int(arr) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```